# How can I write a complex composite chord in Noteflight?

Tags: chords, functional-harmony, noteflight

In functional harmony analysis, the provided image demonstrates a method of representing (one of) the true function(s) of the diminished chord: a dominant seventh flat ninth with no root note and the third in the bass.

[image: Dominant seventh flat ninth with no root and third in bass]

<sup>Example of what a dominant seventh flat ninth with no root and third in bass could look like. Made using GIMP. Apologies for the fake super-/subscripts.</sup>

Noteflight does have a link to this quite helpful [hotkeys guide](https://support.noteflight.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020463271-Keyboard-Shortcuts), but the only kind of chords I have been able to create which has a backslash over the main part, are chords written as degrees (e.g. I, ii, V7 and so forth), i.e. `\6` to represent a missing sixth. (This does not appear to work with Roman numerals – which are treated as letters).

**Is there any way to write a stacked chord which strikes out the main part of the chord with a slash or backslash and adds a specific number or letter as the bass?**

---

Also, it bugs me immensely that they do not use true super-/subscripts for those symbols, instead using resized regular numbers, but that’s a pet peeve for another day. (Well, actually it’s a big one, but I’ll leave it at that.)

Comment: I can't verify this, but my sense is that this is not a possibility built into NoteFlight. It's an American company based on American music education, and my sense is that this notational system, since it's more in vogue in Europe, is probably not high on their priority list.

Comment: If your search for "noteflight is:question" you’ll see that there has been 4 questions containing the word "noteflight" (including your question) with only 2 of them asking specifically about NoteFlight. I do not think this justifies creation of a dedicated tag for this. Also keep in mind that NoteFlight is not an engraving software, but an educational note writing software. This is a feature not even implemented in all professional notation software! This means that probably the only way to do it is to fake it using manually placed text objects.

Comment: @Lazy Maybe I will have to find myself an optical drive and try reinstalling my 20-year-old copy of Finale? Though I am not sure even that (even a modern edition) would support that. 20-year-old? I meant 22.

Comment: @CannedMan As far as I know even modern Finale does not have built in support for this. Sibelius has some kind of support as far as I know, but else the options would be to use a dedicated font for this or to create you symbols in a drawing program and insert them into your score. Lilypond does not natively support it, but it is quite easy to stack such symbols yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature native to Noteflight. Not only is the notation not natively supported in Noteflight, but the Unicode functionality required to display a capital D with slash through it, is also not supported.

For example, to display a capital D (U+0044) with a slash through it, you can use a Unicode combining character. U+0338 is the particular slash you are looking for.

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654793/how-to-place-a-slash-over-the-letter-%C3%B0

Then, you can combine these two characters together by using the dev tools console in a browser such as Chrome, Firefox or Microsoft Edge. Using the copy function, you can place the `̸D` character in your clipboard. This is the line of code you would run: copy('\u0338\u0044');

Then after running this code, you can paste the character wherever you like, but support will vary.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard/246660#246660

And unfortunately, as stated earlier, it is not supported in Noteflight, so this is what it looks like placed into a chord symbol:

[image]

Additionally, even StackExchange displays it in this same incorrect way, if you don't use preformatted text.

Example: ̸D

So essentially, your only option is to fake it.

First, you can start by inputting what you can do in Noteflight natively, by placing a chord symbol, and then typing:
`D7 b9` (listing the first number attached to the letter, and then using spaces will make the chord symbol be displayed using a more figured bass styled notation, but not all the features from Noteflight's figured bass functionality are available).

Then add performance text, enter the number 3, and drag it below the letter D, and then add another performance text, put a single forward slash, and then drag it over the letter D. Your final result should like this:

[image]

So, it's not the real thing, but it at least gives an option (if not a tedious one) for displaying this notation.

Comment: This was a very thorough and extremely helpful answer. Thanks for taking the time to detail this to such an extent. I learned several things I did not know, such as how to use the dev tools to achieve this; I would not have thought of that. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad this could be of some use! I tried to add extra depth to it, since the answer is essentially "no" lol, so I'm glad this answer could be helpful!

Comment: It appears that Finale treats U+0338 in the same incorrect way, though with regards to typography, Finale is pretty rubbish – it doesn’t even have support for the most basic OpenType features (for writing; it is alright for setting sheet music, but certainly not perfect).